# Kubernetes Template for Custom Resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

in Kubernetes there is a way to get the template of the core resources like this:

```bash
kubectl create secret generic --dry-run=client --output=yaml
```

Is there a way to do the same for Custom Resources? I have a lot of CRDs because of crossplane and they have a lot of default values when initially applying the resource. Currently if I want to create one I set the kind and try to get a minimal spec working.

lets assume for the example my crd is: postgresqls.database.example.com

I already tried explain but that shows the types at the end I wanted like a real "applyable" yaml.

```bash
kubectl explain PostgreSQL --recursive
```

and with get I need a preexisting resource:

```bash
kubectl explain PostgreSQL --recursive
```

Happy for further ideas.